# Assembly reference error

Tags: c#, assembly-references

I am referencing the Renci SSH library in my project and I am trying to execute the code. I get an error saying:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Renci.SshNet, Version=2013.4.7.0, 
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find  the file specified.

I checked the properties of the reference and 'Copy local' is set to true.

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be when DLL exists, but it can depends on others - then you still get error "cannot find file"

Use [file monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) during load to find which DLL is missing

Or use [depends](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) utility on ssh library to find the same

Comment: I am using just one dll in the project - Renci.SshNet. Any idea why this is not being detected?

Comment: @user2891821 so, check with file monitor is it really loaded, maybe it looks in wrong places, so you need to copy your dll into proper folder